# Pandas: how to create a list with other line of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column looking like this:

```
Source
1
2
3
```

What I would like to do is a column like this:

```
Source   Related
1        [2,3]
2        [1,3]
3        [1,2]
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Indexing could help. what parameter are you using to for the related. maybe more information might help us help you

Answer (score 2):

Just do a 'costing' way but easy to understand

```
df['out'] = df.Source.apply(lambda x : list(set(df.Source.tolist())-{x}))
Out[29]: 
0    [2, 3]
1    [1, 3]
2    [1, 2]
Name: Source, dtype: object
```